# Flutter - Execution failed for task ':app:multiDexListDebug'

Tags: flutter, android-webview, flutter-dependencies

After adding the plugin webview_flutter_plus and after adding this line in `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in your <project-directory>/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml under application`

and Required Permissions line

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

I am facing the below error. Can anyone help me out to get this fixed?

Error :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:multiDexListDebug'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Error while merging dex archives: 
     Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
     Type io.flutter.plugins.webviewflutter.WebViewFlutterPlugin is defined multiple times: C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\flow-0.1-master\build\webview_media\intermediates\runtime_library_classes\debug\classes.jar:io/flutter/plugins/webviewflutter/WebViewFlutterPlugin.class, C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\flow-0.1-master\build\webview_flutter\intermediates\runtime_library_classes\debug\classes.jar:io/flutter/plugins/webviewflutter/WebViewFlutterPlugin.class

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 47s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: whats your minimun android api?

Comment: minSdkVersion 16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `minSdkVersion` is set to **21 or higher**, multidex is enabled by default and you do not need the multidex support library.

**Below 21 API**

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 15 
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3' // add latest dependency
}
```

Comment: my minSdkVersion 16 and dependencies {
  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3' // add latest dependency
} is already in there. Do I need to change my minSdkVersion ?

Comment: change it to 22 and try

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried enabling multiDex in android folder -> app folder -> build.gradle file?

```
 defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
       
    }
```

Comment: Yes, multiDexEnabled true, still the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

this happens because the library you are using uses the same dependences.
in my case,i use package

```
flutter html : 1.0.0
youtube_player_flutter: ^6.1.0
```

and both packages use the same dependences, namely `webview_flutter` so that the error is

```
io.flutter.plugins.webviewflutter.WebViewFlutterPlugin
```

Solution

1. in VSCode Search (Ctrl+Shift + P)
2. in your error io.flutter.plugins.webviewflutter.WebViewFlutterPlugin search for keywords webview.
3. Find a library that uses the same dependences, then update to the `latest package version`.(Work for me)
4. This solution will keep the library you are using without deleting it.

> ```
> flutter html : 1.0.0
> youtube_player_flutter: ^7.0.0
> ```

Comment: Can you explain point #3 please?
I started getting error after I added `flutter_webview_pro` along with `webview_flutter`